# How to map a Json attribute name to a Java field value

Tags: java, json, jackson

How to map a JSON attribute name to Java field value using jackson?

This:

```
{ "list":[  { "monday":[ "apple", "bread"] } ,
            { "sunday":[ "bacon", "beer" ] } ],
  "kind":"shoplist" }
```

to this:

```
public class StuffList {
    public List<Stuff> list;
    public String kind;
}

public class Stuff {
    public String name;
    public List<String> items; 
}
```

The fragment `"monday":[ "apple", "bread"]` is mapped to two variables, one with the attribute name and another with the attribute value.

Comment: There's an example of this in the [Jackson tutorial](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)

Comment: Edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: Anyway, didnt found how to do that on the tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON represets simple list of maps, more exactly: `List<Map<String, List<String>>>`. You can convert this JSON into this POJO:

```
class JsonEntity {

    public List<Map<String, List<String>>> list;
    public String kind;

    public StuffList toStuffList() {
        StuffList stuffList = createStuffListObject();

        return stuffList;
    }

    private StuffList createStuffListObject() {
        StuffList stuffList = new StuffList();
        stuffList.kind = kind;
        stuffList.list = createItemsList();

        return stuffList;
    }

    private List<Stuff> createItemsList() {
        List<Stuff> items = new ArrayList<Stuff>(list.size());
        for (Map<String, List<String>> item : list) {
            items.add(convertToStuff(item));
        }

        return items;
    }

    private Stuff convertToStuff(Map<String, List<String>> item) {
        Stuff stuff = new Stuff();
        stuff.name = item.keySet().iterator().next();
        stuff.items = item.values().iterator().next();

        return stuff;
    }
}
```

And now we can deserialize JSON in this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String json = "{\"list\":[{\"monday\":[\"apple\", \"bread\"]},{\"sunday\":[\"bacon\", \"beer\"]} ],\"kind\":\"shoplist\"}";

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonEntity jsonEntity = objectMapper.readValue(json, JsonEntity.class);
    System.out.println(jsonEntity.toStuffList());
}
```

Output of the program:

```
list=[[name=monday, items=[apple, bread]], [name=sunday, items=[bacon, beer]]], kind=shoplist
```

Comment: It appears that there is no natural support for direct mapping to a strong type, but your solution is quite elegant, will use that.

Answer (score 1):

Use annotation `@JsonProperty` If you want to change name use annotation with argument, e.g. `@JsonProperty("stuff_name")`

Comment: The example was indeed misleading, I edit it to be more clear

Comment: I hope that the example clarified that it is not a direct field-to-field mapping.